# how to get result's size of va_arg(ap, char *)

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I want to put the result of va_arg(ap, char *) in a string I already declared, so my strategy is to :

1)- get the size of the result of va_arg

2)- malloc the string I already declared

3)- copy va_arg(ap, char *) to the string

But I don't know how to do the first step

```
char    *ft_printf_s(va_list *ap, t_flag *flag)
{
   char  *s;
   size_t size;
   char *str;

   str = va_arg(*ap, char *);
   size = ft_strlen(str); /* ERROR: AddressSanitizer  caused by a READ memory access*/
   s = ft_strnew(size + 1); /* malloc size + 1 then ft_memset(s, '\0', size + 1) */ 
   s = ft_strcpy(s, str);
  return (s);
}
```

I'm getting [image: errors] when I try to get the size of str with str, I think it's because va_arg returns a char* without '\0'

Comment: This indicates that what you passed to this function does not point to a valid string.  Please update your question with a [mcve] that includes how the function it called.  My guess is you need to test for NULL before doing what you're doing.

Comment: A [mre] includes the calling code. It should be a **complete program** that readers can compile and execute without needing to change or add anything. The error message you are getting suggests that `ft_printf_s` is being called with a null pointer. So either you need to fix the error in the caller that passes a null pointer or you need to change `ft_printf_s` so that it accepts a null pointer (such as by testing for it and not creating a string if it was passed a null pointer).

Comment: In your code you are passing in and returning s. how can that be right?

Answer (score 2):

The result of `va_arg(ap, char *)` is a pointer to `char`, a `char *`, so its size is the size of a `char *`. It is not the size of the array or string that the pointer points to (except by coincidence).

If the `char *` points to a string, you can use `strlen` to get the number of characters in the string, as with:

```
char *p = va_arg(ap, char *);
size_t length = strlen(p);
```

When allocating space for a copy, remember to include space for the terminating null character, which is not included in the `strlen` result.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but this doesn't worked for me, I'm getting an AddressSanitizer Error : [image](https://imgur.com/a/DUPAxpw). I think that the result of va_arg(ap, char *) doesn't have a '\0' so strlen search outside

Comment: @yuva It says: `Hint: Address points to zero page` which means `p` in your context might be `NULL`, in what case, the above code will not work. Make sure you are passing the right argument to the variadic list.

Comment: @Ruks here is my [code](https://imgur.com/a/IORquEo)

Comment: @yuva — show your code in the question.  Make it an [MCVE].